# Vaadin flow select component prevent click event propagation to grid header

Tags: vaadin-flow

In Vaadin Flow 23.1.x we have a grid with different filter fields in the header.

In the screen below the "Vendorstatus" is a `ComboBox` and the ValudateCode is a `Select` component.

What we now see:

- If we click in the Vedonrstatus field, the dropdown opens and nothing else happens, which is ok
- If we click in the ValutaCode field, the dropdown opens too, but also the "Sort" of the grid is triggered.

So it looks like the select component does not consume/block the `ClickEvent` from propagating down to the parent components.

Is there a way to prevent the click to trigger the sort of the column grid?

Workaround would be to re-implement my `Select` based header filter with `ComboBox` type ones.

The code to generate the filter header:

```
headerRow.getCell(col).setComponent(createSelectFilter(...));
```

And the createSelectFilter method:

```
private static Component createSelectFilter(...) {
   VerticalLayout vl= new VerticalLayout();
   Label l= new Label("Headername");
   vl.add(l);
   Select<MyobjClass> select= new Select<>();
   select.setItems(...);
   select.getElement().addEventListener("click", 
      event -> {})
      .addEventData("event.stopPropagation()");
   select.addValueChangeListener( e --> updateDataFilter());
   vl add(select);
   return vl;
}
```

This does not stop propagation of the click to open the dropdown and select a value to also trigger a sort "command" on that column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use this method to add the listener them you can

```
select.getElement().addEventListener("click", 
    event -> ...)
.addEventData("event.stopPropagation()");
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Please see updated question